# How to identify pattern-matching indices across columns in lists

Tags: r, list, match

I'm working with speech data, called `turn`, and their Part-of-Speech tags, called `c5`:

```
df_test <- data.frame(
  Turn = c("we 're not gon na know the person",
           "it 's gon na rain"),
  c5 = c("PNP VBB XX0 VVG TO0 VVI AT0 NN1",
         "PNP VBZ VVG TO0 VVI"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I want to identify the indices of the `c5` value that corresponds to the string `gon`; to this end I `str_split` both `Turn` and `c5` into 'word units':

```
library(stringr)
df_test$Turns_split <- lapply(df_test$Turn, function(x) unlist(str_split(x, " ")))
df_test$c5_split <- lapply(df_test$c5, function(x) unlist(str_split(x, " ")))
```

This works okay. The problem is the identification of the matching indices: while I do not get an error I do not get the desired indices:

```
df_test$Index_matches <-  lapply(df_test[,3:4], function(x) match(which(df_test[,3]=="gon"), seq(df_test[,4])))
df_test
                               Turn                              c5                              Turns_split
1 we 're not gon na know the person PNP VBB XX0 VVG TO0 VVI AT0 NN1 we, 're, not, gon, na, know, the, person
2                 it 's gon na rain             PNP VBZ VVG TO0 VVI                    it, 's, gon, na, rain
                                c5_split Index_matches
1 PNP, VBB, XX0, VVG, TO0, VVI, AT0, NN1              
2                PNP, VBZ, VVG, TO0, VVI
```

The correct result would be:

```
df_test
                               Turn                              c5                              Turns_split
1 we 're not gon na know the person PNP VBB XX0 VVG TO0 VVI AT0 NN1 we, 're, not, gon, na, know, the, person
2                 it 's gon na rain             PNP VBZ VVG TO0 VVI                    it, 's, gon, na, rain
                                c5_split Index_matches
1 PNP, VBB, XX0, VVG, TO0, VVI, AT0, NN1             4
2                PNP, VBZ, VVG, TO0, VVI             3
```

How can this result be obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `BaseR`,

```
df_test$Index_matches <-  sapply(df_test$Turns_split, function(x) which(x %in% "gon"))

> df_test$Index_matches 
[1] 4 3
```